# Datagrid Selection Changed Method

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Currently I am trying to write a method to let user click on any datagrid cell or row in the datagrid view and after clicking information from datagrid view appers in the various textboxes / combo boxes. The thing is after clicking on the item it just doesn't work. Last time I when I wrote something else it was datagrid multiselect option which set to ture and caused problems, this time I have no idea what I did wrong. Method itself:

```
private void dataGridView3_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView3.SelectedRows)
   {
      Group selectedGrp = row.DataBoundItem as Group;
      if (selectedGrp != null)
      {
          this.textGrpID.Text = selectedGrp.GrpID;
          this.textGrpName.Text = selectedGrp.GrpName;
          this.comboBoxGrp.SelectedValue = selectedStd.StdGrp;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why use the `SelectionChanged` event then? You didn't mention anything about changing selections... you said the user would click on a cell to see this information... so why not handle the `Click` event instead?

Comment: OMG, That what happens when writing code during all night. Thank you Sheridan, problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

You want to show the textboxs for enter the the free text while clicking the row on datagrid. do u use the Edit template for showing the textbox and dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

Why use the `SelectionChanged` event then? You didn't mention anything about changing selections... you said the user would click on a cell to see this information... so why not handle the `Click` event instead?